How to compensate for vertical offset in fonts?
We recently switched to a different default font in our WPF application and unfortunately, now most labels look like they are positioned ~1 pixel above where they're supposed to be. This is especially egregious when they should be vertically centered inside a TextBox or ComboBox or next to a CheckBox. Other than using a different font, is there a simple way to compensate for this or do we really have to add a margin or something like that to all of our TextBlock and Label styles?

I use a (panel) "Loaded" event handler on one or more "Panels" that iterates over the "Children" looking for "Tags" or an "is a" in order to hook up any other event handlers or do "touch ups" (when more convenient than the alternatives).

It's best to let controls grow to fit content. Which can then mean you need sliders, especially for multi language but even if you don't know for sure the display settings and size to expect.

The controls were already growing to fit content. The problem was about baseline alignment of the font. It turned out to be an actual bug in the font distribution we were using from Google Fonts. We now switched to the original github release from the font's creator and now everything is aligned like we were expecting it to. Thus, this is no longer an urgent issue for me, but I'd still be interested in how to deal with unruly fonts if such a situation should ever arise again in the future.

The baseline of a font does not necessarily work as the basis to determine the vertical center of arbitrary letters. Let's say, if the letters includes a letter which has a glyph over the top of alphabetical letter, the vertical center will be different from those that do not include such letter. I don't think there is an universal solution unless you calculate the vertical center from the glyphs of given letters.
